# InstallShield LE to build an .msi instead of setup.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installshield, installshield-le

I'm trying to "teach" InstallShield LE for Visual Studio 2010 to build a myproject.msi instead of setup.exe

In (6) prepare for Release I've changed in the Setup.exe Tab the value Setup Launcher to "No".
When I build the Project it generates still a setup.exe. Im using SingleImage and I've also switched from Debug to SingleImage.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: for the guy who voted and starred the question. I gave up with Installshield LE and switched to WiX.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that there are multiple release types within the Installshield Project "Prepare for release", you have to make sure you have the the "Setup Launcher" property to "No" on the Setup.exe tab for each Release type (CD_ROM, DVD-5, SingleImage) that you don't want a Setup.exe for.

You also need to confirm that you are building in the Release format that you think you are, check the Solution's Configuration Manager to verify which of the InstallShield LE project formats is being built for each of the release types.

Other things that used to cause this issue is if you are using any of the Installshield redistributable packages. They require the Setup.exe to manage these packages and installation processes for them.